# RSpec how is be_invalid matcher made available

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec-expectations

I noticed following line

```
expect(actual).to be_invalid
```

while I was looking at https://github.com/perfectline/validates_url/blob/81ec1516423af0b4fdc7cabbcda0089e434f2703/lib/validate_url/rspec_matcher.rb#L5

I tried to look for that matcher's implementation in rspec-core, rspec-expectations and rspec-rails gems but I could find only `be_valid` and that too only in rspec-rails https://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FMatchers:be_valid

which made me wonder how does `be_invalid` is made available because when I used that matcher in a test example it didn't raised any not defined method error.

Can anybody please help in making me understand how does that work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that ends in a question mark is called a predicate. They look like this:

```
[].empty?
```

RSpec has a pretty cool predicate matcher that looks like this:

```
expect([]).to be_empty
```

It works by using [`method missing`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/562d327cb951575d13db2a43b232c9ca1456ea6a/lib/rspec/matchers.rb#L961) to select the [`BePredicate`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/562d327cb951575d13db2a43b232c9ca1456ea6a/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/has.rb#L137C13-L137C24) matcher. The matcher works by stripping off the `be_` with a regex and appending a `?`, then `send`ing that method to the subject of the expectation.

`be_valid` and `be_invalid` are no different. Both [`valid?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5534a2286b17e361ebfdca078e411578ed493e83/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L363) and [`invalid?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5534a2286b17e361ebfdca078e411578ed493e83/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L402) are defined on ActiveModel::Validations.

So, if you're doing this:

```
expect(User.new).to be_invalid
```

RSpec is using its predicate matcher to call `User.new.invalid?` and return the result. Same goes for `be_valid`. Unless, that is, you're using `RSpec::Rails`, which contains a `BeValid` matcher that overrides RSpec's predicate matcher so that it can print out all the validation errors when the spec fails.